# Adobe Air Compile Ext JS application

Tags: extjs, adobe

I want to compile my Ext JS application with Adobe air but it's not working, a lot of errors of undefined comes on Console.

When I compile simple HTML page then it's working fine.

Please let me know what will be solution for this.  Thanks

Comment: What version of ExtJS and Adobe Air are you using?

Comment: Ext JS Version is 5.1.1 & Above air version is18.0.0